# Como confirmar se usuário existe com aqueles "ticks verdes"

Tags: javascript, ajax, alert

Dizem que é com javascript, mas procurei na net e não acho nada relacionado...

Exemplo de como quero que fique: [image: Imagem com ticks]

Atualmente eu faço com Alerts, porém gostaria que validação deixasse um sinal verde como a da imagem(ver canto direito) em caso de sucesso e um vermelho em caso de falha.

O que tenho até agora:

```
if(isset($_POST["botao"])) {
$name        =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["name"]);
$surname     =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["surname"]);
$birthday    =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["birthday"]);
$sex         =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["sex"]);
$username    =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["username"]);
$email       =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["email"]);
$password    =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["password"]);
$repassword  =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["repassword"]);

if($name == "" || $surname == "" || $birthday == "" || $sex == "" || $username == "" || $email == "" || $password == "" || $repassword == "") {
echo "<script> alert('Preencha todos os campos.'); </script>";
return true;
}
if($password != $repassword) {
echo "<script> alert('As senhas devem ser iguais!'); </script>";
return true;
}
// FAZ A BUSCA NO BDD PRA VER SE O EMAIL JA EXISTE
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE email='$email'");
if(select) {
$row = $select->num_rows;
if ($row > 0) {
echo "<script> alert('Já existe um usuário com este e-mail!'); </script>";
} else {
// FAZ A BUSCA NO BDD PRA VER SE O USUARIO JA EXISTE
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username='$username'");
if(select) {
$row = $select->num_rows;
if ($row > 0) {
echo "<script> alert('O Usuário já existe.'); </script>";
} else {
// CASO TUDO ESTIVER OK ELE INSERE AS INFORMAÇÕES NO BDD
$insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `data`(`name`, `surname`, `birthday`, `sex`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `status`) VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$birthday', '$sex', '$username', '$email', '".md5($password)."', '0')");
if($insert) {
echo "<script> alert('Usuario registrado com sucesso!'); location.href='login.php' </script>";
}}}
else {
echo $mysqli->error;
}}
}}
?>
```

Obrigado a quem tentar me ajudar!

Comment: Poderia explicar um pouco mais o que realmente deseja?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode resolver esse problema utilizando o callback de success da sua requisiçao AJAX.

Você pode manter sua lógica de validação existente, mas deve retornar um resultado (result) para a função AJAX e invoca-la sempre que um botão for clicado, ou quando o input for alterado.

```
var username = $('#username').val();
    $('#username').change(function() {
       $.ajax({
          url: "validacao.php",
          type: 'POST',
          data: 'username=' + username,
          success: function(result){
                     if(result > 0){
                         // faça alguma coisa se o usuário já exista
                     }
                     else{
                         // faça alguma coisa se o usuário ainda não exista
                     }
                   }
          });
    });
```

Se você não conhece bem AJAX, pode dar uma olhada [neste link](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/checking-username-availability-with-ajax-using-jquery/), explica mais detalhadamente como funcionam requisições AJAX com um exemplo parecido com o que você precisa fazer :)

Comment: Poxa, esqueci de agradecer! Muito obrigado pela ajuda, deu tudo certo... e aprendi um pouco sobre ajax também! ^^